# Can I be capped on the amount of tokens that I can send?

Tags: solidity

There is a token that says it only allows you to sell 350 million of its tokens(0.05 BNB) at any one time. Would this mean that I can also not send them to another wallet? Or is it limited to selling in pancake swap from my wallet?

Thank you in advance

Comment: you are asking about business rules on technical forum, so we can't answer your question. Etherscan doesn't have sources published for BNB token so we can't tell for sure what did they implement inside contract. Techincally you can transfer a maximum of 2 power 256 amount of tokens in Ethereum

Comment: We need a contract code to ensure this. Though I can surely say that I know such tokens, they are usually a scam because an owner can change the limit of selling, so better stay away from them.